# Supermicro IPMI is not working

Tags: ipmi, supermicro

I got a problem with two supermicro-servers which are placed in a housing-place.
No documentation for this nodes has been made. I tried to setup the IPMI because it shouldnt be a big problem. I did this via Bios, and configured the xxx.xxx.xxx.52 for the IMPI (the normal address would be xxx.xxx.xxx.50), the netmask and the gateway. I still cannot connect to the IMPI-controller neither via the network nor directly connected from server to laptop.

I heard from a another person, that he did exactly the same thing to a other supermicro-server and it worked. He did not know, where the problem could be.

Does someone have an idea about what could be the problem with the IMPI and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

most sincerely

Twinhand

Answer (score 3):

If you plug a Windows laptop directly into the IPMI port, reboot the laptop and type 'arp -a' it should (hopefully) show you what IP address the IPMI port is advertising, this should help.

Answer (score -1):

Please make sure that your IP address setting is correct. Try to unplug the power cable and then plug it back after few minutes.
If still doesn't work you can try to check the firmware version and update to the latest version if it possible.

You can also contact Supermicro customer support and they will help to solve your problem.